# RXJS flow for waiting until element blur before subscription runs

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I want to track when an input's value changes and only when the element is blurred do I want the subscription to fire.

Of course I could do something like what I have below, but that's of course not very elegant. Any suggestions?

```js
fromEvent(inputElement, 'input)
  .subscribe((e) => {
    fromEvent(inputElement, 'blur')
      .subscribe((blurEv) => {
        // Do something with inputElement.value
      });
  });
```

I guess I could just listen for the blur event, but there are still certain circumstances I would need to track minute input changes before the blur happens

Answer (score 0):

First, you should never subscribe within a subscribe.  You can use observable flattening operators like **concatMap**, **mergeMap**, and **switchMap**.  So the easiest thing you can do is fix that.

```
fromEvent(inputElement, 'input').pipe(
  switchMap(() => fromEvent(inputElement, 'blur'))
).subscribe((blurEv) => {
  // Do something with inputElement.value
});
```

Honestly it's hard to come up with something better unless without knowing more of your needs.  The one issue with this is that the event subscription is going to get created after each input.  You could solve that with **merge** and **scan** if you need to maintain a state.

The following uses **merge** to subscribe to focus and blur events only once.  When focused an object with an *oldval* property is emitted, and when blurred an object with a *newval* property is emitted.  The emissions are merged with the prior state using **scan** to create a new state.  This will have the effect of creating an object with *oldval* and *newval* properties that can be compared.

```
merge(
  fromEvent(el, 'focus').pipe(map(x => ({ oldval: el.value, state: 'hasfocus' }))),
  fromEvent(el, 'blur').pipe(map(x => ({ newval: el.value, state: 'lostfocus' })))
).pipe(
  scan((acc, cur) => ({ ...acc, ...cur }), {}),
  filter(x => x.state === 'lostfocus')
).subscribe(/* Do something */);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const blur$ = fromEvent(trackedEl, 'blur').pipe(take(1))

fromEvent(trackedEl, 'input').pipe(
   distinctUntilChanged(),
   switchMap(() => blur$)
).subscribe((v) => {
    // Do work
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the [`updateOn`](https://indepth.dev/posts/1311/the-update-on-option-in-angular-forms#the-updateon-option-in-reactive-forms) option to `blur`, then `form.valueChanges` will only emit when a field is blurred:

```js
export class AppComponent  {

  form = this.fb.group({
    name  : '',
    age   : '',
    email : ''
  }, { 
    updateOn: 'blur'
  });

  subscription = this.form.valueChanges.subscribe(
    value => console.log('>>> value on blur:', value)
  );

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }

}
```

Here's a basic [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-70804209?devtoolsheight=50&file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) demo.